# How to merge, sort and loop over JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript

I have a loop which returns integer values and objects like the following:

```
2
{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:28, eyeColor:"blue"}
3
{firstName:"Jane", lastName:"Doe", age:22, eyeColor:"brown"}
1
{firstName:"Jack", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"red"}
```

Those are different values returned line by line inside a loop.
I need to loop over the objects, based on the sort order of the numbers and get both the number and each object in two different variables. 
What I need to get and be able to loop over it is:

```
1
{firstName:"Jack", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"red"}
2
{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:28, eyeColor:"blue"}
3
{firstName:"Jane", lastName:"Doe", age:22, eyeColor:"brown"}
```

so i will be able to use it in a function like this:

```
loop sorted 
    some_function(number_variable, object_variable);
end loop
```

I need them to get called in specific order because they are used for grid column reordering.

I tried to push the objects in an array but how am I going to sort those based on the other number values?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code that generates the first result you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a result array of object based on numbers as `index = number-1`

```
var nums = [2,3,1];
var objects = [
{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:28, eyeColor:"blue"},
{firstName:"Jane", lastName:"Doe", age:22, eyeColor:"brown"},
{firstName:"Jack", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"red"}
];
var sortedObjects = nums.map(function(num) {return objects[num-1]});
sortedObjects.forEach(function(obj, i) {some_function(nums[i], obj)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
How you recommend to build the two arrays? In my loop I'm getting those in separate lines. For example first I have 2 and {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:28, eyeColor:"blue"} then 3 and {firstName:"Jane", lastName:"Doe", age:22, eyeColor:"brown"} and last 1 and {firstName:"Jack", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"red"}.
And how can I call the some_function in the correct order 1, 2 , 3 because like this the forEach is calling it in that order:
    {firstName: "Jane", ...}
    {firstName: "Jack", ...}
    {firstName: "John", ...}

Comment: @WilliamBird then you can omit prelast line of code and use only last one but with `objects` variable name:  `objects.forEach(function(obj, i) {some_function(nums[i], obj)})`

Comment: But they are not called in the correct order like that. And how I will build the two arrays?